# jquery plugin Fullcalendar, drag events between calendars in view: agendaDay

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have using this last code modification but this only works in "basicDay" view, I have try to modify this but its don't seems to work.
https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=550

Any suggestion?
Please guys...